# Is this line from Underscore.js doing equality checking actually necessary?

Tags: javascript, equals, equality

I've just been looking at the `_.isEqual` function of Underscore.js and a section of the code goes something like this:

```
if (a === b) return true;

if (typeof a !== typeof b) return false;

if (a == b) return true;
```

I'm just wondering if there's any case where the third statement could be reached and evaluate to `true`?

*Edit: Just to be clear, this isn't my own code I'm talking about, I'm reading the source of Underscore, in particular, [this line](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L616) and I was curious about why they're doing that.*

Comment: There's got to be some weird edge case where this is possible...

Comment: @nickf: Considering that `==` and `===` are identical when the types are the same, I can't see how the first and third tests would ever provide a different result. Even in the case of `null` where the `typeof` differs from the internal `Type`, it doesn't coerce to any value except `undefined`, which has a different `typeof` value. And if there *is* some edge case out there, how do you know that you'd *want* it to coerce? Just seems strange to have a `==` and a `===` test of the same values. Either you want type coercion or you don't.

Comment: ...I should clarify that by *"you"* in the comment above, I didn't mean to imply *nickf*, but rather *a person*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just been browsing through the Underscore repo and came across a short discussion where someone asked [the exact same thing](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/pull/244#r90217), and it looks like it is actually unnecessary.

Following the algorithm defined by the ECMAScript Language Specification in [section 11.9.6](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.9.6) and [section 11.9.3](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.9.3) seems to show that no pair of values should return true in the above case.

So, in short, **no, that situation is not possible**.

Answer (score 1):

The only situation where `==` and `===` react unexpectedly is when comparing a literal string (`"123"`) to a constructed string (`new String("123")`), which would fail the first test.

However, on the second test it gets caught because the constructed string has the type `object`, but the literal has the type `string`.

Based on that, I'd say no, the third statement can never be reached, and evaluate to true.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `==` operator and the expressions are of different types, JavaScript will generally convert the two into the same type before comparing.

For example, this can happen with `null` and `undefined`. `null == undefined` is true, even though `null === undefined` is false. However `typeof null` is `"object"`, while `typeof undefined` is `"undefined"`. So, in this case you should return false on the second statement.

You can read all the details in the spec (section 11.9.3), it is very involved:
http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

Answer (score 1):

My initial guess was that it was to work around a broken browser implementation.

However after digging into the git logs for that file it looks like the corresponding line was in the very first `underscore.js` checkin. (I'm not gonna hunt in the parent documentcloud `core.js` repo...) You can see it at line 334 of https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/commit/02ede85b539a89a44a71ce098f09a9553a3a6890 .

So now my guess is that its just cruft that got left in, never completely tested and never cleaned out.